# jQuery variable issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, append

My attempt to find the name of the div holding a select box, then put this div into a variable which is used elsewhere in my jQuery code, does not seem to be working. Another piece of code is appending extra divs to the page, these have select boxes of class .parent within them. However many extra divs I append, the code below always appends to the first div added, even though checking through a browser the div structure works as expected. I'm new to jQuery so don't know if I'm missing something obvious, but I'm pretty sure the variable div below should be redefined each time .parent element is changed as it is part of the variable's definition. When I've run an alert just to check the variable name it is always defined as sub_cat_1. This is correct for the first appended div class of show_sub_categories but thereafter it should be sub_cat_2, sub_cat_3 etc incrementing. As said the select boxes are definitely in the correct divs on the page, so I can only asssume I'm missing something simple with this bit of the code below. (basic html at bottom for reference)

```
$('.parent').livequery('change', function () {
    var div = $(".parent").closest("div").attr("id");
    $(this).nextAll('.parent').remove();
    $(this).nextAll('input').remove();
    alert(div);
    $('#' + div).append('<img src="images/system/loader2323.gif" style="float:left" id="loader" alt="" />');

    $.post("get_chid_categories.php", {
        parent_id: $(this).val(),
    }, function (response) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            finishAjax(div, response);
        }, 400);
    });

    return false;
});
```

This is just to show you the basic structure of the divs being appended.

```
<p id="add_field"> … </p>
<div class="show_sub_categories">
    <div id="sub_cat_1">
    <select class="parent" name="search_category"> … </select>
    <select class="parent" name="sub_category"> … </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show_sub_categories">
    <div id="sub_cat_2">
    <select class="parent" name="search_category"> … </select>
    <select class="parent" name="sub_category"> … </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've put a very simplified version of this at http://www.0urs.com/fiddle/experience1.php just to illustrate the physical location of the appended select boxes.

Comment: where did you find this livequery()?

Comment: Unless you have to use some ancient version of jQuery, the livequery plugin is unnecessary. Latest versions have the same functionality built-in using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @Antonis it was an example I found as jQuery is totally new to me. Will look to switch livequery out for .on() but I take it this isn't the problem here?

Comment: make a jsFiddle, it will help us answering.

Comment: @Antonis I'm trying to make a jsFiddle at the moment, the more immediate problem with that is it doesn't have livequery library and when I switch out livequery for on() in my script it doesn't run.

Comment: @Antonis I've put a barebones version of my page onto my own server so you can have a look there. It's a bit of a play to make it work with no DB connection but it illustrates the problem. If you add a couple of divs and then refresh the select box on any other than the first one, you'll see it appends the next select box inside the top div http://www.0urs.com/fiddle/experience1.php  ... Hope this helps you understand my problem

Comment: You have to upgrade to a more recent version of jQuery if you want to increase the chance of getting help. jQuery 1.3 is old (sorry, ancient).